# `read.csv()` imports text column as numeric

Tags: r, csv

I have a file "data.csv" with a few columns:

```
col1, col2, col3
001,  012,  0234
```

All three columns have strings like the data displayed, but when I run `df = read.csv("data.csv")`, `View(df)` looks like this.

```
col1, col2, col3
1,    12,   234
```

How do import the data to look the way it does in the CSV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `colClasses` in `?read.csv`:

```
df = read.csv("data.csv", colClasses="character")
```

> **colClasses**: character.  A vector of classes to be assumed for the
>             columns.  If unnamed, recycled as necessary.  If named, names
>             are matched with unspecified values being taken to be ‘NA’.
>
> Possible values are ‘NA’ (the default, when ‘type.convert’ is
>             used), ‘"NULL"’ (when the column is skipped), one of the
>             atomic vector classes (logical, integer, numeric, complex,
>             character, raw), or ‘"factor"’, ‘"Date"’ or ‘"POSIXct"’.